# Let λ be an eigenvalue of A. Prove that λ+a is an eigenvalue of A+aI.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let λ be an eigenvalue of A. Prove that λ+a is an eigenvalue of A+aI.

That is a question I may find in a test next monday. I think my approach is valid, but if it is, the question looks too simple to be in the test!

Av = λv, v≠0

Av + av = λv + av

(A+aI)v = (λ+a)v

Is that it? Thanks guys

Comment: Yes that is it, all the working is done correctly. You can add some explenations of what you are doing/showing, and write the conclusion explicitly, depending on your teacher's requirements (proof writing).

Comment: @AnyAD explicitly

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks, done.

Comment: Welcome! Nice question $\ddot\smile$ You can improve it by using [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr), although I really appreciate the effort you’ve gone to to make it look legible and neat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct! (Answering as community wiki so this question may be closed as answered)